# Pricebook object not available whilce creating sandbox template

Tags: sandbox, pricebook

I am trying to create a sandbox template to setup a partial sandbox, I want to include data from Pricebook and product objects but I don't see them listed in the objects list. 
Am I missing something?

Comment: Pretty sure they are included in a create/refresh sandbox anyway?

Comment: What objects list? Please note custom and standard objects are listed in different parts of the setup page left menu.

Comment: I am not seeing Pricebook in the object list on the sandbox template form - see screenshot - https://imgur.com/gxETMpV

Answer (score 2):

The product and price books are copied automatically to sandboxes. You don't have to include them into the sandbox template. Those are copied automatically even to developer sandbox and therefore also existing in partial sandbox as well.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000188411&type=1